# $stateParams, how to pass value from one state to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

On a ionic/Angularjs project, 
When one item is clicked in a list in a state, how do I set a rule to pull data on the next view thanks to the itemID of the item clicked in this list ?

The code is too long to paste here, but you 'll get the idea in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmun0mkx/4/)

I want from clicking on items in  gray color in the list, update informatino of the detaild view of that item  (in blue background).

HTML of list view :

```
        <h1 class="featured_in_mag_name">Dishes in that category:</h1>        
    <ion-item ng-repeat="dish in dishList | selectedDishType:selection ">
       <article class="item_frame">
          <h4 class="item_name_english">{{dish.nameEnglish}}</h4>
          <p class="item_name_local_language">{{dish.nameLocal}}</p> 
        </article>
        <!--main article frame 1 -->
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

HTML of detailed view

```
<ion-view view-title="Dish " >
   <h1 class="featured_in_mag_name">Selected dish - detailed view:   </h1>    
    <ion-content>
   <article class="detailed_view">
      <h1 class="item_name_english">{{dish.nameEnglish}}</h1>
      <p class="item_name_local_language">{{dish.nameLocal}}</p>
      <p class="item_name_local_language">{{dish.nameLocal}}</p>    
      <p class="item_name_local_language">{{dish.description}}</p>
      <p class="item_name_local_language">{{dish.region}}</p> 
      <p class="item_name_local_language">{{dish.country}}</p>
    </article>              
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is using the $state service. $state.go will transition to the new state and can accept parameters for that state. These parameters can then be accessed in the new state's controller through $stateParams.

For your example it would be something like this

In the list view:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="dish in dishList | selectedDishType:selection " ng-click="$state.go('detailsState', { id: dish.itemID })">
```

Then, in the next state you can grab the id in your controller from $stateParams like this:

```
function controller($stateParams) {
    var itemId = $stateParams.id;
}
```

Keep in mind that to have this work you will have to setup your state with a route like this:

```
$stateProvider.state("detailsState", {
   url: "/details/:id"
});
```

All of these are a part of the ui.router module. For more info see http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Comment: thanks a lot, I had managed to find  and fix the issue before your answer, but definitely sounds like a good option too

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you basically should :

- *pass* the id in the url (process depending on which router you're using), example `/bear/:id`
- let your router process the redirection
- then in the *detailled-view* controller *re-fetch* the object from your storage (usually through a service), and *load* it into your template via `$scope`

This way, you'd get 2 **independant**, pretty **stateless**, routes linked to each other. Stateless here means that if you access, say, `/bear/2`, even just typing the url, you will get the view coresponding to the resource bear 2, which is strongly semantic, just like REST endpoints.

In addition, you can note that the pattern you describing is called **Master-Details** =)

Comment: thanks Cyril (you must be french!?) I had found  this pklr http://embed.plnkr.co/DBSbiV/preview ,  will dig into it and hopefully implement solution correctly..

Comment: Yep French. I'll post some code later. But before I had to check if I'm realy talking about what you need. Was I ok ?

Comment: (me too!) looking at it this morning, but new  in both js/angularjs/ionic so takes a bit of time ..

Comment: Just checked the plunker, I had never seen this kind of (one pager) implementation using `$state` . But this is basically the same approach that I described, implemented with _ui-router_

Comment: yep looks like. I am currently looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988151/aungular-ui-router-child-using-parents-view also using $state  but somehow do not manage to adapt the solution ... may be because of te filter  set in the master controller...